# Subscribing to exact-online webhook with java

Tags: java, webhooks, exact-online

Exact-Online WebHook-docs:
https://support.exactonline.com/community/s/knowledge-base#All-All-DNO-Content-webhookstut

## 1) Exact-Online webhook-subscription flow:

### a) You send a POST-Request:

#### *URL:*

```
https://start.exactonline.be/api/v1/{division}/webhooks/WebhookSubscriptions
```

#### *Headers:*

```
Authorization: Bearer {acces_token}
Content-Type: application/json
```

#### *Body:*

```
{
    CallbackURL: 'https://{domain}/WebHook',
    Topic: 'FinancialTransactions'
}
```

The callback-URL-domain should be the same as the Redirect-URI you've utilized to register your app in the exact-online app-center.

### b) You receive a POST-request on your CallbackURL

You controller listening to the CallBackURL should thus return a HttpStatus 200 || 201 telling the exact-online server that there is a controller listening for that CallBackURL.

Once the exact-online server receives your HttpStatus == 200 || 201, you are subscribed to the topic. Everytime a financial action is performed from that point on, the exact-online server will send you a request on your CallBackURL.

#### Expected result:

The expected result of this flow is you get a response back from the exact-online server after you send them your HttpStatus.OK telling you you are now subscribed.

#### Actual result:

Though when I try this I get an error message:

*'Invalid: Post to callback URL endpoint returns 500 An error occurred while sending the request.'*

From this error I can conclude that my CallBackURL is correct and matches the redirect-URI in my app-registration, but from debugging I know the request never reached my controller.

## 2) What I did:

### a) I send the POST-request through postman:

- For the moment I'm running my java-backend locally, so i filled {domain} with my public-IP I get when searching for 'what's my ip' on google.
- I don't see any reason why this flow couldn't be done starting from a postman-request, I hesitated to try and do the 'a)'-request directly from my java-backend, but I don't see how this could solve the problem.

### b) My controller to receive the post-request:

```
@RestController
public class WebhookController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/WebHook", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> webhook(@RequestBody(required=false) ExactWebHookResponse exactWebHookResponse) {
        //handle exactWebHookResponse
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

- The only real problem I could see from my controller is the `(required=false)` in my `@RequestBody`. But knowing the request never reached my controller, this shouldn't solve my problem. Though if this isn't applicable, please let me know.

## 2) What I think is the problem:

- The flow only works through 'https', so for now I requested a self-signed certificate through keytool, added this in my backend code, added some code in my application.properties so that Tomcat connects on 8443 port.
  (For more info, I followed this guide: https://drissamri.be/blog/java/enable-https-in-spring-boot/).
  I didn't redirect HTTP requests, so only https requests are accepted. But that shouldn't be a problem because the flow doesn't utilize http.
- I'm asking myself: could this only work through a trusted CA?
- Is the problem the fact my domain is my Public IP?

For the actual production I will be running my backend on an Amazon Linux EC2 server, I don't know how to fully configure the server yet so it accepts https, the only thing I know is that getting a certificate through the Automated Certificate Manager from Amazon is impossible for IP-address domains. I already tried running my backend through the server and changing the domain of my redirect-uri and callback uri to the Elastic IP of my server, but that didn't work, probably because I haven't set up anything on that server yet (the only thing I did was adding HTTPS-rule to my security group).

- Would this all be solved if I properly configured the server to accept https and use a self-signed certificate and have my redirect-uri and callbackUri-domain set on the Elastic-IP of my server?

please help.

Comment: Should indeed use a proper certificate and server must be reachable on URL from AWS nodes used to distribute the webhook events. Note that with large volumes of companies you can easily receive 200 events per second during prolonged periods of time.

Comment: @Guido Leenders Wait wait wait, I found a public DNS of my instance. So I should use that as domain and ask a certificate based on that DNS? so for ex. my public DNS is: 'ec2-{elastic-ip}.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com', my domain would be: 'https:// ec2-{elastic-ip}.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com'. Correct? If that's the answer to this question, you saved my life ;) Thanks for the note btw, but that won't apply for me

Comment: Tried to ask for a certificate through the Amazon ACM, but won't allow certificates for domain-names ending with amazonaws.com. Is that still the correct domain I should use as CallbackURL and I should try getting a certificate through another way than amazon?

Comment: I think I found the answer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html#letsencrypt